# How can I write into a particular line of a file in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to write some data taken from a file into the last line (not in new line) of a file. I am using the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Write the start and end file number:"
read sta end 
echo "$sta" "$end"

for (( c="$sta"; c<="$end"; c++ ))
do
   cp AnalyzeClusterParameterFile AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c
   awk '{if (NR== '$c' -10){print $1 " " $2 " " $3}}' center.dat >>  AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c 

done
```

But it (AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c file) is going to new line like this

> Rinner          = 0.1   ! in Mpc
>
> Router          = 5     ! in Mpc
>
> NumberOfPoints  = 50     ! default is 16
>
> VirialDensity   = 200    ! default is 200
>
> CenterListName =
>
> 5.044627347e-01 5.008533222e-01 5.043365095e-01

What i actually want(AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c file) is

> Rinner          = 0.1   ! in Mpc
>
> Router          = 5     ! in Mpc
>
> NumberOfPoints  = 50     ! default is 16
>
> VirialDensity   = 200    ! default is 200
>
> CenterListName = 5.044627347e-01 5.008533222e-01 5.043365095e-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a newline character at the end of `AnalyzeClusterParameterFile`. You can remove it by replacing the `cp` command with:

```
head -c -1 AnalyzeClusterParameterFile > AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c
```

Beware, that this will kill any trailing character, not just newlines!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the line with sed.

catcenter.dat

`sed -i "/CenterListName/ s/=$/= $(cat center.dat)/" AnalyzeClusterParameterFile$c`

Read the value first and add it to the second file with sed.